# Graficar ventas mensuales

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy aprendiendo a trabajar con Pandas, necesito graficar las ventas mensuales por vendedor. No logro dejar los meses en el eje x.

El resultado que estoy buscando es:

- Eje Y monto de la venta
- Eje X el mes
- Leyenda el nombre del vendedor

Estos son los datos resumidos, son 12 vendedores en total:

```py
data = [
    {'vendedor': 'Roger Perello', 'enero': 400014, 'febrero': 82200, 'marzo': 209284, 'abril': 389306, 'mayo': 284439,
     'junio': 155002, 'julio': 396104, 'agosto': 128716, 'septiembre': 402521, 'octubre': 354949, 'noviembre': 468952,
     'diciembre': 206369},
    {'vendedor': 'Joan Davila', 'enero': 441462, 'febrero': 158867, 'marzo': 79985, 'abril': 187237, 'mayo': 240034,
     'junio': 471695, 'julio': 419148, 'agosto': 110195, 'septiembre': 56499, 'octubre': 245531, 'noviembre': 86356,
     'diciembre': 484004},
    {'vendedor': 'Karim Alcaide', 'enero': 293093, 'febrero': 277494, 'marzo': 249823, 'abril': 128366, 'mayo': 306874,
     'junio': 360516, 'julio': 232845, 'agosto': 237800, 'septiembre': 151506, 'octubre': 337652, 'noviembre': 278197,
     'diciembre': 120233}
]
```

Genero el DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head(10)
```

Genero la grafica:

```py
pl = df.plot(kind='line')
```

Este es el resultado que obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes acomodar los datos antes de realizar el grafico, traspón el DataFrame para que las columnas con los meses pasen a ser índice y asigna como columnas los vendedores:

```
data = [
    {'vendedor': 'Roger Perello', 'enero': 400014, 'febrero': 82200, 'marzo': 209284, 'abril': 389306, 'mayo': 284439,
     'junio': 155002, 'julio': 396104, 'agosto': 128716, 'septiembre': 402521, 'octubre': 354949, 'noviembre': 468952,
     'diciembre': 206369},
    {'vendedor': 'Joan Davila', 'enero': 441462, 'febrero': 158867, 'marzo': 79985, 'abril': 187237, 'mayo': 240034,
     'junio': 471695, 'julio': 419148, 'agosto': 110195, 'septiembre': 56499, 'octubre': 245531, 'noviembre': 86356,
     'diciembre': 484004},
    {'vendedor': 'Karim Alcaide', 'enero': 293093, 'febrero': 277494, 'marzo': 249823, 'abril': 128366, 'mayo': 306874,
     'junio': 360516, 'julio': 232845, 'agosto': 237800, 'septiembre': 151506, 'octubre': 337652, 'noviembre': 278197,
     'diciembre': 120233}
]

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
trasposed = df.iloc[:, 1:].T
trasposed.columns = df.vendedor
pl = trasposed.plot(kind='line')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfecto.